# Getting line count of docx file using java poi jar

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx, line-count

I need to get the line count of the docx file created using poi jar. I used the below code

```
XWPFDocument doc1 = new XWPFDocument(POIXMLDocument.openPackage("LineCounter.docx"));
System.out.println("lines using method 2 --> " + doc1.getProperties().getExtendedProperties().getUnderlyingProperties().getLines());
System.out.println("word 2 --> " + doc1.getProperties().getExtendedProperties().getUnderlyingProperties().getWords());
```

Above code works only when i copy the content of the created docx into new file.

Comment: How is your Word document being generated? By something other than Word perhaps?

Comment: Only word will change the properties of the document when saved, most of the developer tools aren't that complete that they can do this (it would basically require a rendering engine)

Comment: You can try line count softwares like linecount manager but they are not free tools